# Yarn (Node and Resource Manager) not Running, Hadoop 3.2.1 Installation Windows 10

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

## Summary

Installing Hadoop following this [guide](https://gist.github.com/vorpal56/5e2b67b6be3a827b85ac82a63a5b3b2e), everything goes fine until Step 7 (starting NameNode and DataNode) but when I'm trying Step 8 (starting NodeManager and ResourceManager) the two cmds open up but they fail with the following excpetions each.

nodemanager cmd:

```
2022-11-18 18:29:44,278 ERROR nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.<init>(ProviderMethod.java:256)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:71)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:275)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:144)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:123)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:349)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.build(WebApps.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.WebServer.serviceStart(WebServer.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:1054)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7c0c77c7
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:200)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:194)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:56)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:46)
        ... 32 more
2022-11-18 18:29:44,286 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping server on 57727
2022-11-18 18:29:44,287 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 0
2022-11-18 18:29:44,287 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2022-11-18 18:29:44,288 WARN monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2022-11-18 18:29:44,297 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8040
2022-11-18 18:29:44,298 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8040
2022-11-18 18:29:44,298 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2022-11-18 18:29:44,299 WARN nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2022-11-18 18:29:44,299 INFO localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Public cache exiting
2022-11-18 18:29:44,299 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
2022-11-18 18:29:44,300 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
2022-11-18 18:29:44,301 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2022-11-18 18:29:44,301 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at my-computer-name/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
************************************************************/
```

resourcemanager cmd:

```
2022-11-18 18:29:43,321 FATAL resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:64)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.<init>(ProviderMethod.java:256)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:71)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:275)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:144)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:123)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:349)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.build(WebApps.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startWepApp(ResourceManager.java:1231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:1340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1535)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @222545dc
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:200)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:194)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:56)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:46)
        ... 29 more
2022-11-18 18:29:43,329 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2022-11-18 18:29:43,329 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2022-11-18 18:29:43,330 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at my-computer-name/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
************************************************************/
```

---

## Details of my Attempt

- Using JDK 18.0.2
- Environment variable JAVA_HOME is C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk-18.0.2 (because "Program Files" had some issues earlier)
- I do not have yarn package manager installed

---

## Reader's Note

In case there are important details missing let me know to add them.

Comment: I am thinking it is a JDK version issue but from what I searched there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was actually the JDK version, I used the one on the guide and it worked just fine.